# java keystore and password changing

Tags: java, keytool

I changed pass of my keystore:

```
keytool -list -storetype JCEKS -keystore store.jceks -storepasswd -new secret
```

here I have 3 entry

```
        passwd = new char[] { 's', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't' };
        fis = new FileInputStream("myKeys.jceks");
        ks.load(fis, passwd);
KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry skEntry = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) ks.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(
        passwd));
```

here I got exception:

```
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Given final block not properly padded
```

can you help me what is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found my mistake. I have to firstly run keypasswd for all entries:

```
keytool -keypasswd -storetype JCEKS -keystore myKeys.jceks
```

and then storepasswd:

```
keytool -storepasswd -storetype JCEKS -keystore myKeys.jceks
```

for whole keystore.

Comment: Do you know any single command to change password of all the keys in a keystore together?

Answer (score 2):

May be you changed the password of the key-store but not of the key-entry? 
Both can be changed individually.

```
passwdStore = new char[] { 's', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't' };
passwdEntry = new char[] { 'p', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', '2' };
fis = new FileInputStream("myKeys.jceks");
ks.load(fis, passwdStore);
KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry skEntry = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) ks.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(passwdEntry));
```

Comment: but I dont want to change key entry

Comment: Then you should not use the same passwdord for reading the store and loading the entry (see my updated answer).