# java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Given final block not properly padded

Tags: java, keytool

I have changed the password for my keystore, which has a bunch of keys,
using the following command:

`keytool -storepasswd -storetype jceks -keystore my.keystore`

and then I input old pwd and then the new one twice.

But since then I keep getting the following error:

```
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Given final block not properly padded
```

So, where is the problem :(? Any ideas?

Comment: Did you do some research; like just searching for that exception message? Getting to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635742/exception-in-thread-main-java-security-unrecoverablekeyexception-given-final for example?

Answer (score 1):

When you change the keystore password only the storepassword change and the password for all the key entries in the keystore remain unchanged. So you will have to first change passwords of all the keys and then change the keystore password. [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665801/java-keystore-and-password-changing/9668318#9668318)

First run keypasswd for all entries:

```
keytool -keypasswd -storetype JCEKS -keystore myKeys.jceks
```

and then storepasswd:

```
keytool -storepasswd -storetype JCEKS -keystore myKeys.jceks
```

for whole keystore.